# received data through UART showing on 7 segment display using ATmega16

Tags: avr, atmega, uart, 7segmentdisplay

I am writing code for Atmega16 for receiving data from another PCB through UART. I want to display the data on a 7-segment 4-digit display, but when code for UART and 7-segment is enabled the data is not shown. I measured no power in ATmega16 pin that is connected to the 7-segment display.

When I disable the UART and display a fixed value, for example 62, it does show up on the display. I shared the code below.

```
#define BAUD RATE 2400

void uart_init(void);

void segment(int value);
void print(int number);

int temp;

/**********************************************************/
/**********************************************************/

char s = 0;

int data;

int frequency = 0;

void USARTInit(uint16_t ubrr_value)
{
    //Set Baud rate
    UBRRL = ubrr_value;
    UBRRH = (ubrr_value >> 8);
    UCSRC = (1 << URSEL) | (1 << UCSZ0) | (1 << UCSZ1); //UCSZ2>0 for 8bit
    UCSRC = (1 << UPM1); // for even parity: UPM1>1, UPM0>0....USBS>0 for stop bit
    UCSRB = (1 << RXEN) | (1 << TXEN) | (1 << RXCIE);
}

char USARTReadChar(void)
{
    //Wait until a data is available
    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << RXC))) {
        //Do nothing
    }
    return UDR;
}

void USARTWriteChar(char data)
{
    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << UDRE))) {
        //Do nothing
    }
    UDR = data;
}

ISR(USART_RXC_vect)
{

    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << RXC)))
        ; //execution will wait till the
            //whole byte packet is received

    data = UDR;
    s++;

    if (data == 0xAA) //0xAA is header byte that is sent from another device
    {
        s = 0;
    }

    else if (s == 3) {

        frequency = data; //byte no 3 is frequency
        segment(frequency);
    }
}

int main(void)
{

    DDRB = 0xff;
    PORTB = 0x00;
    DDRD = ~(1 << 0);
    DDRA = 0x0f;
    PORTA = 0xf0;

    sei();

    USARTInit(207);

    while (1) {

        // frequency=62;
        //segment(frequency);
    }
}

void segment(int value)
{

    temp = value / 1000;

    print(temp); //4th digit print
    PORTA = 0x01;
    _delay_ms(1);

    temp = value / 100;
    temp = temp % 10;
    print(temp); //3rd digit print
    PORTA = 0x02;
    _delay_ms(1);

    temp = value / 10;
    temp = temp % 10;
    print(temp); //2nd digit print
    PORTA = 0x04;
    _delay_ms(1);

    temp = value % 10;
    print(temp); //1st digit print
    PORTA = 0x08;
    _delay_ms(1);
}

void print(int number)
{

    if (number == 0) {
        PORTB = 0x3F;
    } else if (number == 1) {
        PORTB = 0x6;
    } else if (number == 2) {
        PORTB = 0x5B;
    } else if (number == 3) {
        PORTB = 0x4F;
    } else if (number == 4) {
        PORTB = 0x66;
    } else if (number == 5) {
        PORTB = 0x6D;
    } else if (number == 6) {
        PORTB = 0x7D;
    } else if (number == 7) {
        PORTB = 0x7;
    } else if (number == 8) {
        PORTB = 0x7F;
    } else if (number == 9) {
        PORTB = 0x6F;
    } else {
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got blocking code for both the LED display scan and the UART. Preferably re-write it with interrupt-driven code for both, but at least one. Use a timer interrupt for the display scan.

Comment: The code you've written as your UART ISR would work better as just a normal function called from `main()` rather than an ISR. Blocking loops like that `while` you have are rarely (if ever) a good idea in an ISR.

Comment: How can overcome this issue. please help me to write the code. where I can modify.

Comment: Try writing a single loop which checks say 1000 times to see if there is a UART character.  If you get a character immediately process it and move on to cycle to displaying the next digit and resume checking.  **But even if after that number of times you do not have a UART character, *still* go on and cycle to the next display digit**.  Adjust the number of UART checks larger or smaller until the display works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never want to have a waiting loop like this within an interrupt service routine:

```
ISR(USART_RXC_vect){
    while (!(UCSRA & (1 << RXC)))
        ; //execution will wait till the whole byte packet is received
}
```

One reason is that you do not know how long it will take, and it can take so much time that other interrupts that are supposed to go off just cant, because you are waiting in an interrupt handler. This can lead to unexpected behaviour. Instead use a flag, simply create a boolean and set that to true when the interrupt goes off like this:

```
// Necesarry includes

// Function prototypes/definitions

// Interrupt flag for usart receive
bool usart_rxc_flag = false;

int main(){
    // Set up port direction
    // Initialize timers, interrupts and usarts here

    // Variables
    char usart_receive;

    while(true){
       // Sleep

       // Receive UART
       if (usart_rxc_flag)
       {
           // Read char into variable
           usart_receive = usart_read_char();

           // Send data to segment display
           segment_send(usart_receive); 

           // Reset flag
           usart_rxc_flag = false;
       }
    }
}

ISR(USART_RXC_vect){
    usart_rxc_flag = true;
    // Other simple stuff you might wanna do
}
```

The code is not complete of course, that's up to you. But this should really get you in the right direction. I have commented places where you need to put your code, like initalize your usart etc.

I have assumed you have reasons for using interrupt to receive the uart data, like reducing power consumption for example. If this is not important, then you could simply use what's called a polling-method in the main loop to continually check for uart messages and save them on the go.

Comment: It is important to know that what is the difference between Atmega8 and Atmega16 for UART.

Comment: What do you want to know about the differences in UART? Do you mean how to handle and set up UART in software and how they differ between Atmega8 and Atmega16?